# How to set a principal point for a camera

Tags: rendering, camera

Pinhole camera model includes a principal point (just to be clear, it appears here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model)

Is there a way to set these camera param s.t. it will be used for rendering an image?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but it sounds like the lens's Shift properties.
[image: Camera lens settings]

Here's the default settings:
[image: Default shift values]

And here's the same camera with an X-axis shift of 0.2:
[image: X-axis shift at 0.2 - Y-axis remaining at 0.0]

Note that this is not the same as simply rotating the camera - adjusting the Shift doesn't change the perspective. You can think of it as if you had a larger image and you cropped a side of it off.

Comment: Do you know how to achieve this in blender python?

Comment: Dumb follow-up question: Does anyone know the units for this? The docs don't indicate anything: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html

Comment: It's answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58235/what-are-the-units-for-camera-shift

Answer (score 7):

The Cycles render engine is so realistic, you can create your own pinhole camera (http://bensimonds.com/2013/03/04/cycles-experiment-pinhole-camera/). While this is cool, what I think your really asking is how to set the center of the image(or maybe the exposure):

> A point R at the intersection of the optical axis and the image plane.
>   This point is referred to as the principal point or ***image center***.
>   (*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model)*)

You can set the center of the image by positioning the camera (use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to fly the camera).

If you're talking about exposure (how much light is allowed to touch the film), you can change that in the Cycles render panel under film:

[image: Exposure Settings]