# What is blender's camera projection matrix model?

Tags: transforms, camera, coordinates, conversion

I have question what is blender's camera projection model.

I want to use blender to my computer vision experiment which need to compare real photo and CG. For real photo, I used camera matrix K for perspective projection, like this

```
 K= [f 0 Px 0]
    [0 f Py 0] 
    [0 0  1 0]
```

(Px and Py is center coordiate of 2D image, start from Top-Left to Bottom Right)

So I can easily transform 3D vertex to 2D pixel coordinate. To compare this matrix, I need to know how blender make camera matrix K in it's internal rendering process. It seems that blender's camera has 3 parameters (f (focal length), near plane, far plane. Ignoring shift x and y).

How to make blender's camera projection matrix which transform 3D vertex to 2D image coordinate from these 3 paremeters?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9203/599

Comment: I checked that post and find perspetive matrix generation method, but it is complete same with OpenGL's perspective matrix expression. It has left, right, top, bottom, near, far parameters. But I don't know how actually blender's camera settings converted to that parameters. Do you know any thing that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following Python code builds a calibration matrix K commonly used in computer vision from a Blender camera. You can then use the generated K matrix to compare against your own.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

def get_calibration_matrix_K_from_blender(camd):
    f_in_mm = camd.lens
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    resolution_x_in_px = scene.render.resolution_x
    resolution_y_in_px = scene.render.resolution_y
    scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
    sensor_width_in_mm = camd.sensor_width
    sensor_height_in_mm = camd.sensor_height
    pixel_aspect_ratio = scene.render.pixel_aspect_x / scene.render.pixel_aspect_y
    if (camd.sensor_fit == 'VERTICAL'):
        # the sensor height is fixed (sensor fit is horizontal), 
        # the sensor width is effectively changed with the pixel aspect ratio
        s_u = resolution_x_in_px * scale / sensor_width_in_mm / pixel_aspect_ratio 
        s_v = resolution_y_in_px * scale / sensor_height_in_mm
    else: # 'HORIZONTAL' and 'AUTO'
        # the sensor width is fixed (sensor fit is horizontal), 
        # the sensor height is effectively changed with the pixel aspect ratio
        pixel_aspect_ratio = scene.render.pixel_aspect_x / scene.render.pixel_aspect_y
        s_u = resolution_x_in_px * scale / sensor_width_in_mm
        s_v = resolution_y_in_px * scale * pixel_aspect_ratio / sensor_height_in_mm

    # Parameters of intrinsic calibration matrix K
    alpha_u = f_in_mm * s_u
    alpha_v = f_in_mm * s_v
    u_0 = resolution_x_in_px*scale / 2
    v_0 = resolution_y_in_px*scale / 2
    skew = 0 # only use rectangular pixels

    K = Matrix(
        ((alpha_u, skew,    u_0),
        (    0  ,  alpha_v, v_0),
        (    0  ,    0,      1 )))
    return K

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Insert your camera name below
    K = get_calibration_matrix_K_from_blender(bpy.data.objects['Camera'].data)
    print(K)
```

### Notes

- I've tested this with cycles and many scenes, and it works.
- The updated code is now well-tested with non-unit aspect ratio in different scenes.
- Non-zero skew is not supported in blender AFAIK.
- The principal point assumed fixed at the center of the image. If this is not so, this code needs to be updated to take camera shift into account (see [How to set a principal point for a camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/883/how-to-set-a-principal-point-for-a-camera))
- Lens distortion is taken into account separately, see my answer to [Distortion Coefficients and Camera intrinsic of blender's cameras?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38208/distortion-coefficients-and-camera-intrinsic-of-blenders-cameras/38460#38460)
- I'm ignoring your last column containing all zeros.
- The code is written explicitly for documentation purposes. I apologize for the long names and extra variables but it really pays off for debugging careful parameter conversions.
- To get the full "projection matrix which transforms 3D vertex to 2D image coordinates" you mention in the end of your question, see my answer to [3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera).

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, rfabbri. I tested your code and found some problem about fy (alpha_v) in non-uniform  aspect image (1280x960). I projected mesh to camera, the x of projected position is correct, but y is looks incorrect. I modified your code to `aspect_ratio_resolution = resolution_x_in_px / resolution_y_in_px` `s_v = resolution_y_in_px * scale * aspect_ratio / aspect_ratio_resolution / sensor_height_in_mm` Then I got correct result. But I don't know what I did. Can you explan about this?

Comment: Also I found that the original and modified code does not work for non uniform pixel aspect (non-square pixel).

Comment: @KichangKim what is your sensor fit setting? (next to sensor size: Auto, Horizontal or Vertical)?

Comment: @KichangKim I've updated the code (and tested it). Thanks. The pixel aspect ratio is a render context setting, technically not really a physical camera parameter but part of the projection model which takes into account the pixel aspect ratio to be displayed. I am certain that the example you tried had a vertical sensor fit; this reverses the way the aspect ratio influences pixel coordinate computation in blender (I checked this against blender's internal code logic in addition to testing it). If the fit is vertical, the aspect is inverted so it needs to be applied to x.

Comment: Thanks for updating code. I found that small mistake in your code, duplicating pixel_aspect_ratio calculation in HORIZONTAL and AUTO mode :)

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in this script. I have a camera with resolution 640x320, focal length 18 and sensor width 32. Regardless of which sensor fit I choose, the focal length is (360, 320) but it should be (360, 360) -- which I verified by rendering a calibration pattern. You can find my blend-file here: https://ufile.io/1a231

Comment: I've also found the similar problem with camera resolution 640x480, sensor fit AUTO, and the corrected focal length is (640, 640), but is shown (640,853). How can we reason about that?

Comment: I (think I) fixed the problems with this function [in my modified version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120063/3581).

Comment: the solution of rfabbri is overly complicated and computes the wrong alpha_v he also includes the image aspect ratio there. Also it merely fixes the principal point at center. See https://www.rojtberg.net/1601/from-blender-to-opencv-camera-and-back/ for a shorter and complete solution.

Comment: @user927543 if you are so sure please write a proper answer. I have no time to check everything. but thanks for trying!