# Implement own camera model in Blender

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I need to create real-world cameras with Blender.

My target workflow is:

1. Use OpenCV to calibrate the camera model
2. Use the results of OpenCV to create the exact same camera in Blender

Since Blender has other camera parameters (for example, OpenCV has a focal length in `x` and `y` direction and Blender only one focal length value) a direct mapping is not possible.
I found some sources like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-blenders-camera-projection-matrix-model) where people provide a function to convert the matrices from OpenCV to Blender and vice-versa.

These are nice approaches but do not exactly fit my requirements.
I need to be able to, for example, simulate a fisheye lens.
I know that "compositing" provides a lot of possibilities but I would like to directly create a camera lens instead of processing the image afterwards.

My question is if it is possible to implement a new camera where I can use parameters as I create them?
For example to implement a camera where I can set the `focal_x` and `focal_y`.