# What are the units for camera shift?

Tags: camera

I'm having trouble making sense of the units of a camera lens shift.  It ranges from `-2,2`, defaulting to `0`, but it doesn't seem to be in scene units, nor does it seem to be in radians.

Anyone have an idea what the values represent?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be in percentage or fraction of the render size (in pixels).

That means that a lens shift of `1` shifts the camera exactly one frame unit in a certain direction, making it frame exactly outside the previous default framed area.

This is measured however in relation to the **largest dimension** of the rendered frame size. So lets say you are rendering in Full HD, that is `1920 x 1080` pixel image; a frame shift if `1` unit will shift exactly `1920` pixels in any direction, that is up/down/left/right.

This may seem obvious while shifting sideways towards the X axis, but might seem random while shifting in the Y axis.

[image: Camera Shift]

Comment: Very insightful!  Accepted.  I was only tweaking the y-shift, so it did indeed seem random.  Thank you.

Comment: @user48206, Duarte, this is not random : have a look at the camera shape from outside in ortho view (the 3D View ortho, not the camera ortho)

Comment: Yes, I know it's not random as stated in my answer, I meant it *might seem* random while controlled from the smallest render dimension, since `1` unit will not correspond to exactly one frame size shift.

Answer (score 2):

For the Calculation of the smaller dimension* with the Resolution of $1920$x$1080$. If the larger dimension $1920$ has a Value of $1.0$, than the value to shift the camera along the full smaller dimension of $1080$ is:

$1080$px$/1920$px$= 0.5625$