# Pinhole Camera?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera, light

I would like to know if the default camera generated by blender 2.9 is based on the pinhole model, or if I can apply this model to it? If not, how can I generate a pinhole camera with blender?

*I saw a post where someone generated one with Blender like an object. However, I would like to know how to do this using python.*

Thank you for your answer. Have a lovely day and weekend.

Comment: Related: [How to set a principal point for a camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/883/31447)

Comment: *"The Cycles camera is a pinhole model that uses the distance between a given point and the pinhole as its Z depth."* from: [Cycles generates distorted depth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131053/31447).

Comment: Thank for your 2 comments. I will look at the 2 links you gave me.